# File archiver that stores RAW EFS files

Tags: windows, backup, encrypting-file-system, utilities

I'll start off with the assurance that I have all the EFS certs safely in hand, and that is not what I'm asking about below.  Assume I have that part taken care of.

I'm trying to backup a some mixed (EFS 10% /nonEFS 90%) files, but want to keep the EFS files encrypted so the backup is not a single point of failure.  I found the `robocopy /EFSRAW` switch, but was hoping there was an archiver (`tar`, `pkzip`, `winrar`) that could do the same type of operation.

I imagine there is some meta-data associated with EFS files beyond just their certificate.  This is likely an EFS like ACL of some sort, as best I can determine.  So the fact that `robocopy` can pull this off on an `NTFS` to `NTFS` clone seems to imply that it's possible.  An archiver would need to account for the *EFS-ACL* and keep track.

Here's a list of workarounds available and why they aren't what I'm after:

1. Archive in unencrypted format - Bad since the archive could be lost with all the secrets in it.
2. Just encrypt whole archive - Bad because 90% of my files don't need this, only the ones with the EFS attribute.
3. Transcode EFS encryption to GPG encryption - Fair, but seems a lot of kluge and hackish.
4. Robocopy files to a VHD then compress it - OK, but single-file extractions would require the whole VHD to be blown up.

Not sure how popular EFS is, but I love it, and wish it had more tooling and support.

Thoughts on a solution, since I think my previous attempts fall short.

Comment: Properly encrypted data, and AFAIK EFS is proper, can't be compressed http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2008/05/15/why-can-i-not-compress-and-encrypt-a-folder-in-windows.aspx so I'd say go with the VHD.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 true, but my content is mixed... 90% non-EFS, 10% EFS.  I'm probably leaning towards the GPG approach.